# Sql short circuit OR or conditional exists in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, shortcut

I'm trying to force sql server to make a short circuit OR comparison on some fields. On the left side of the Or I have a simple variable comparison and on the right side I have a pretty 'heavy' subquery.

```
WHERE
(@Var = 'DefaultValue' )  OR 
Exists(select * from atable)
```

Is there any way to only execute the right side of the or statement if the first statement is false.

I've tried case and if else statements but can't find any working syntax.

I'm using a MS SQL server

Comment: If this is for searching, please read [Dynamic Search Conditions in SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog. If it's something else, I'm afraid Conrad's correct - there's no *guaranteed* way to control evaluation order in a query (including any CTEs or subqueries)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing me to the article. That should give me and my colleagues something to read this weekend :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want in a single SQL statement. You can do something like this however in a stored proc

```
If @Var = 'DefaultValue' then
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM table 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM table
     WHERE Exists(select * from atable)
END
```

If you've got a lot of inputs you should consider Dynamic SQL

Comment: I've used a version of this using a select INTO and adding the where clause inside the If Else block so the code was much easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
WHERE 1 = CASE @Var
               WHEN 'DefaultValue' THEN 1
               ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM atable)
          END
```