# Will SQL Server be smart enough to not execute expensive queries if it is not needed ? (short-circuiting)

Tags: sql, sql-server, short-circuiting, short-circuit-evaluation

So SQL Server does not have short-circuiting in the explicit manner as with for example if-statements in general-purpose programming languages.

So consider the following mock-up query:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable
WHERE name = 'someValue' OR name in (*some extremely expensive nested sub-query only needed to cover 0.01% of cases*)
```

Let's say there are only 3 rows in the table and all of them match name = 'someValue'. Will the expensive sub-query ever run?
Let's say there are 3 million rows and all but 1 could be fetched with the name = 'someValue' except 1 row which need to be fetched with the sub-query. Will the sub-query ever be evaluated when it is not needed?

If one has a similar real case, one might be ok with letting the 0.01% wait for the expensive sub-query to run before getting the results as long as the results are fetched quickly without the sub-query for the 99.99% of cases.
(I know that my specific example above could be handled explicitly with IF-statements in an SP, as suggested in this related thread:
[Sql short circuit OR or conditional exists in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646009/sql-short-circuit-or-or-conditional-exists-in-where-clause)
but let's assume that is not an option.)

Comment: The SQL boolean operators are not guaranteed to short-circuit, neither are they guaranteed not to. The optimizer may or may not elide clauses depending on how the execution plan ends up, which in turn depends on lots of other factors, so there's no simple answer. In principle, as far as semantics go, you must assume they do not short-circuit. Using `CASE` is more reliable than boolean operators, but not 100% guaranteed to leave out unnecessary clauses either (but still much more consistent). If you need performance that's likely a better option.

Comment: You may argue that the subquery is not needed when all rows are equal `someValue`, but even if one doesn't, it is needed. If you are saying you are going to have at least one row not equal to `someValue`, then yes, it will need to be executed, there is no way around it. It will most likely be executed when all rows are `someValue` anyway though. If it has to remain a single query, make it two queries, for `= 'someValue'` and for `<> 'someValue' and (expensive)`, and `union all` the results into one. That still won't guarantee it though.

Comment: FWIW, I ran the code in your question with the subquery referencing a large table with no useful index. The large table was never touched with 3 'someValue' rows because the plan included a startup expression filter to short-circuit. YMMV depending on many factors so the behavior cannot be generalized.

Comment: @DanGuzman
Thanks all for the comments, very interesting. In my actual case the "expensive sub-query" was not really that expensive so I just went the easy route since the performace loss was neglible, but it sparked my curiosity. Good to keep stuff in mind not to always trust the execution plan to resolve the best way possible I guess

Comment: If the execution plan isn't smart enough to work it out, it may help to create indexes, statistics or constraints to give it enough clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, the optimizer in SQL Server is pretty smart.

You could attempt the short-circuiting by using `case`.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states:

> The `CASE` expression evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied.

Note that there are some exceptions involving aggregation.  So, you could do:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM someTable t
WHERE 'true' = (CASE WHEN t.name = 'someValue' THEN 'true'
                     WHEN t.name in (*some extremely expensive nested sub-query only needed to cover 0.01% of cases*)
                     THEN 'true'
                END)
```

This type of enforced ordering is generally considered a bad idea.  One exception is when one of the paths might involve an error,such as a type conversion error) -- however, that is generally fixed nowadays with the `try_` functions.

In your case, I suspect that replacing the `IN` with `EXISTS` and using appropriate indexes might eliminate almost all the performance penalty of the subquery.  However, that is a different matter.